Sended from Blockchain to Jade and nothing on account
Five days ago, I transferred a small amount of BTC from my Blockchain.com account into my Jade Green wallet.
Next day and my Blockchain account was empty and was record for transferring all my BTC.
On Jade was only record for receive small amount like intended.
Now no sign of my whole BTC amount on any account, just growing number of confirmations on Jade explorer and unspent on spending tx.
Sorry to bother you, but I am rookie in this field and looks like I lost my retirement savings.

When you make a bitcoin payment, the transaction will usually have two transaction outputs. One output going assigning the requested payment to the recipient and a second change output that sends the remaining amount from the inputs back to the sending wallet. If you inspect your transaction, you should see the small amount that you sent to the Jade and the change going back to your Blockchain wallet. If this transaction is still unconfirmed, it may look on your wallet like it is not part of your spendable balance. If the transaction is confirmed and you see the expected outcome in the Jade, but not in your Blockchain wallet, your wallet may be out-of-sync. Try to verify that the wallet is caught up to the network, or otherwise try to get it to synchronize.
